# Safari - Display Favicons In Favorites Bar

Tags: safari, safari-extensions

Is it possible to display favicons in Safari's Favorites Bar? For example, my Favorites Bar in Firefox looks like this:
[image: Favorites Bar]

I've tried using glims, but can't get it to do this.

Comment: At present there is no way to add favicons to Safari's bookmarks bar.

Comment: have you found a way to solve this?

Comment: No, I have not.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I was looking for something similar as I use the Chrome bookmark bar in that way, but I couldn't find anything suitable. So I made an extension and have submitted it to Apple, Favicon Bar:

https://github.com/RoryCombe/FaviconBar

[image: FavIcon Bar screenshot]

Comment: nice, but too bad you have to enter the links manually in the extension settings :(

Comment: The link to FaviconBar is no longer working.

Comment: @MichaelFulton Link updated

Answer (score 2):

I don't believe that it can be done as of in Safari 8.

In Chrome, you can simply remove the name associated with the site bookmark and it will only show the favicon in the Bookmarks Bar.  Unfortunately, doing this in Safari results in a bar of "NO_TITLE" instead.

Answer (score 2):

There now is a solution to this: I have created [Faviconographer](https://faviconographer.com/), an app that will overlay Favicons for Safari tabs and favorites bar entries. It's still a workaround compared to a native Safari feature, but it works surprisingly well.

Answer (score 2):

A partial solution is to use `Emoji & Symbols` from the `Edit` menu. MacOS lets you add these pretty much anywhere. Some "symbols" are even English letters in different fonts. As an example, here are two bookmarks in my Favorites Bar, where Overleaf is a regular bookmark and "Email This" uses emojis and symbols.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

As of Safari 8, favicons no longer show up on the tab bar, to my disappointment.

One solution is to use [SafariStand](http://hetima.com/safari/stand-e.html) & [EasySIMBL](https://github.com/norio-nomura/EasySIMBL/). Once installed (see [instructions](http://safaristand.tumblr.com/post/29345453051/how-to-install-safaristand) on the SafariStand site), open the SafariStand settings and check "Show Icon on Tab Bar". This will return favicons to the tabs.

Answer (score -2):

Seemed impossible to me when using Safari. No better for an Apple store assistant. But it's a cinch with Chrome, Firefox and MS Edge.
Chrome - right-click > Edit ... Delete the name.
Firefox - right-click > Properties > Delete the name.
Edge - right-click > Show Icon Only

It's such a simple idea - I'm sad I didn't think of it earlier !

Comment: This question is explicitly about Safari